# Airflow-Runtimeerror:Can't start new thread

Tags: python, airflow

I'm using airflow 1.10.9 with default configuration in cfg file.

Dagfileprocesor is running in background with min_file_process_interval as '2 sec'.scheduler is throwing following error.

```
Runtimeerror:Can't start new thread
```

Scheduler is coming to standstill state,all jobs were showing as running in UI.But jobs were not running in background.

I'm using local executor.

Comment: Do you think the error is related to an issue in your code?

Comment: No..Im just calling bashoperator..I believe some config issues..

Comment: Scheduler is not even stopping by itself after this error..it leads to standstill state..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was due to OS level threads. Not related to Airflow. After increasing OS threads, issue resolved.